# Angular 4 performance / CPU usage on IE11

Tags: angular, performance, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on a angular 4 application. It runs fine on chrome & firefox but the performance on IE11 the load times are unacceptable. Router changes on Chrome/FF are about 0.5s (for more elaborate pages) and about 5s on IE11. Opening a dropdown (by adding/removing a CSS class to set `display:none`) is instant on Chrome/FF and takes about 3 seconds on IE11.
The IE11 profiler shows the following when opening a dropdown:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJwzw.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6X7o.png)
And the timeline is completly full of `classList.add()` and `classList.remove()` calls:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0VNi.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGaWS.png)
It's the same couple of elements on which classes are added/removed over and over again. Buttons

The dropdown simply uses the `[ngClass]` directive:

```
  <div class="dropdown-menu"
       [ngClass]="{
       'show': open,
       'mod-dropup': dropup,
       'mod-right': rightAlign
       }">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
```

I added all of the required polyfills in the `polyfills.ts`. What could be the cause of this?

Versions:
Angular 4.4.3
Internet Explorer 11.1884.14393.0

Comment: did you ever figure this out ? facing same issue....

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem was too many document event listeners.

I had a onClickOutside directive that registers a document click listener and every entry in the table had a dropdown that uses this directve. So when I display 100 entries every click anywhere causes 100 event listeners to fire.

I optimized this by only having a single document click listener in a click service and the directive only (un-)registers the element with the service.

Here's the service:

```
/**
 * A event emitter that should be notified about some kind of click related to the element
 */
export interface ClickListener {
  element : ElementRef;
  emitter : EventEmitter<Event>;
}

/**
 * A central service for managing click handlers
 * This is mainly an optimization to reduce the amount of global click event handler
 */
@Injectable()
export class ClickService {

  private clickOutsideListeners : ClickListener[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.registerClickHandlers();
  }

  private registerClickHandlers() : void {
    document.addEventListener('click', (event : Event) => {
      this.handleClickOutside(event);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Emits for every registered callback if the click is outside of the element
   */
  private handleClickOutside(event : Event) : void {
    this.clickOutsideListeners
      .filter(entry => !entry.element.nativeElement.contains(event.target))
      .forEach(entry => {
        entry.emitter.emit(event);
      });
  }

  /**
   * Registers a listener to be notified whenever there is a click outside of the element
   */
  public addOutsideClickListener(element : ClickListener) : void {
    if (this.clickOutsideListeners.indexOf(element) !== -1) return;
    this.clickOutsideListeners.push(element);
  }

  /**
   * Unregisters the listener
   */
  public removeOutsideClickListener(element : ClickListener) : void {
    const index = this.clickOutsideListeners.findIndex(entry => entry === element);
    if (index === -1) return;
    this.clickOutsideListeners.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

The Directive:

```
/**
 * Emits a event when there has been a click outside of the host element
 */
@Directive({
  selector: '[mdeOnClickOutside]',
})
export class OnClickOutsideDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Output() mdeOnClickOutside : EventEmitter<Event> = new EventEmitter();

  /**
   * (Un-)registers a click listener with the global click service
   */
  @Input() set mdeOnClickOutsideActive(active : boolean) {
    this.inputReceived = true;
    const clickCallback = {
      element: this.element,
      emitter: this.mdeOnClickOutside,
    };
    if (active) {
      this.clickService.addOutsideClickListener(clickCallback);
    } else {
      this.clickService.removeOutsideClickListener(clickCallback);
    }
  }

  private inputReceived : boolean;

  constructor(private element : ElementRef, private clickService : ClickService) {
  }

  /**
   * Activates click listener if it has not explicitly been set
   */
  ngOnInit() : void {
    if (this.inputReceived) return;
    this.mdeOnClickOutsideActive = true;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() : void {
    this.mdeOnClickOutsideActive = false;
  }

}
```

and then use it like this in the template of some other component:

```
<div (mdeOnClickOutside)="clickOutside()">Something</div>
```

with the function in the component:

```
clickOutside() {
    console.log('Somebody clicked somwhere outside');
  }
```

Comment: hi Manuel can you share the service you created ? i am stuck at the same state..... thanks

Comment: Which dropdown did you used? Angular-material?

Comment: @ShaulNaim We build a custom dropdown component with bootstrap CSS - but that doesn't have an impact on the performance issue from this post

Comment: thanks, the issue is that I am using ngx-bootstrap and I experience very slow performance on ie11 when opening dropdown it takes up to 6 seconds to open... and I realized its because I have actions drop-down in every row and they all listen to the click event on body and IE don't deal with it well... how can I override the bootstrap behavior or should I implement a custom drop-down can you suggest? thanks.